# Full text search on large documents

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to find a way to optimise a full text search of a materialised view containing resumes as I'm coming up against performance issues. Any best practices would be appreciated.

My query looks as follows:

```
select
  r.id,
  r.first_name,
  r.last_name

from user.candidates_mv r

where r.ts_resume @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'nurse | doctor')
```

This takes about 1 or 2 minutes to run, re-running it drops to 1.5 seconds. I'm unlikely to be in the situation where I can rely on the cache since the tsquery is provided by the end-user who is searching and will generally be fresh.

- The candidates table has about 2,000,000 records
- Each resume is about 10,000 characters in length
- The ts_resume field is a simple tsvector with a GIN index
- The tsqueries can be very long, made up of many 'or', 'and' and also words near each other such as 'specialist <-> nurse'

Example of long tsquery:

```
'((mechanical <-> design) | (mechanical <-> engineering) | (mechanical <-> engineer) | (development <-> engineer) | (senior <-> design) | (principal <-> design) | (principle <-> design) | (lead <-> design) | (chief <-> design) | (senior <-> mechanical) | (principal <-> mechanical) | (principle <-> mechanical) | (chief <-> mechanical) | (lead <-> mechanical) | (product <-> design) | (senior <-> product) | (principal <-> product) | (principle <-> product) | (lead <-> product) | (chief <-> product)) & ((solidworks) | (solid <-> works)) & ((special <-> purpose <-> machinery) | (special <-> purpose <-> machine) | (special <-> purpose <-> machines) | (high <-> speed <-> machinery) | (high <-> speed <-> machines) | (high <-> speed <-> machines) | (high-speed <-> machine) | (high-speed <-> machines) | (high-speed <-> machinery) | (automated <-> machinery) | (automated <-> machine) | (automated <-> machinery) | (automated <-> machine) | (automated <-> machines) | (automation <-> machinery) | (automation <-> solution) | (automation <-> solutions) | (automated <-> solution) | (automated <-> solutions) | (conveyor <-> system) | (conveyor <-> systems) | (motors) | (servo) | (gearbox) | (gearboxes) | (drive <-> system) | (drive <-> systems) | (test <-> rig) | (test-rig) | (test <-> rigs) | (test-rigs))'
```

When combined this seems to create a lot of work for the DB to cut down to to what is something like 10k results.

Any help, alternative strategies or additionally where clauses are appreciated.

I am also in a position where I can increase RAM/HDD & update any relevant pg_settings. Current stats are: 8GB RAM & 100GB HD space, settings have been decided according to pg_tune

**Edit: Added Explain query** FYI, this was cached as I had previously ran the search

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on entities.candidates_mv c  (cost=10000001184.01..10000001191.96 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=187.902..233.306 rows=2656 loops=1)
  Output: c.id
  Recheck Cond: (c.ts_description @@ '( ''design'' <-> ''engineer'' | ''mechanical'' <-> ''design'' | ''mechanical'' <-> ''engineering'' | ''mechanical'' <-> ''engineer'' | ''development'' <-> ''engineer'' | ''senior'' <-> ''design'' | ''principal'' <-> ''design'' | ''principle'' <-> ''design'' | ''lead'' <-> ''design'' | ''chief'' <-> ''design'' | ''senior'' <-> ''mechanical'' | ''principal'' <-> ''mechanical'' | ''principle'' <-> ''mechanical'' | ''chief'' <-> ''mechanical'' | ''lead'' <-> ''mechanical'' | ''product'' <-> ''design'' | ''senior'' <-> ''product'' | ''principal'' <-> ''product'' | ''principle'' <-> ''product'' | ''lead'' <-> ''product'' | ''chief'' <-> ''product'' ) & ( ''solidworks'' | ''solid'' <-> ''works'' ) & ( ''injection'' | ''injected'' ) & ( ''mold'' | ''mould'' | ''molds'' | ''moulds'' | ''molding'' | ''moulding'' | ''moldings'' | ''mouldings'' | ''moldable'' | ''mouldable'' | ''molded'' | ''moulded'' )'::tsquery)
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 288
  Heap Blocks: exact=2471
  Buffers: shared hit=18560
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on candidates_mv_ts_description_idx  (cost=0.00..1184.01 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=186.334..186.334 rows=2944 loops=1)
    Index Cond: (c.ts_description @@ '( ''design'' <-> ''engineer'' | ''mechanical'' <-> ''design'' | ''mechanical'' <-> ''engineering'' | ''mechanical'' <-> ''engineer'' | ''development'' <-> ''engineer'' | ''senior'' <-> ''design'' | ''principal'' <-> ''design'' | ''principle'' <-> ''design'' | ''lead'' <-> ''design'' | ''chief'' <-> ''design'' | ''senior'' <-> ''mechanical'' | ''principal'' <-> ''mechanical'' | ''principle'' <-> ''mechanical'' | ''chief'' <-> ''mechanical'' | ''lead'' <-> ''mechanical'' | ''product'' <-> ''design'' | ''senior'' <-> ''product'' | ''principal'' <-> ''product'' | ''principle'' <-> ''product'' | ''lead'' <-> ''product'' | ''chief'' <-> ''product'' ) & ( ''solidworks'' | ''solid'' <-> ''works'' ) & ( ''injection'' | ''injected'' ) & ( ''mold'' | ''mould'' | ''molds'' | ''moulds'' | ''molding'' | ''moulding'' | ''moldings'' | ''mouldings'' | ''moldable'' | ''mouldable'' | ''molded'' | ''moulded'' )'::tsquery)
    Buffers: shared hit=2379
Planning time: 0.300 ms
Execution time: 233.996 ms
```

Comment: Try setting `enable_seqscan` to `off` temporarily to check if the index can be used. If yes, compare the execution times to see if PostgreSQL did right not to use the index.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have added the explain to my question, the biggest penalty comes from that initial Bitmap Heap Scan, it looks like the index is used later however. Turning off the `enable_seqscan` `off` did not seem to affect the plan.

Comment: That execution plan looks pretty much perfect to me.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I guess there just is a lot to work for the DB to do on a fresh search, maybe optimising the query itself isn't the issue but server performance may be.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the RUM index extension: https://github.com/postgrespro/rum

The RUM index is similar to GIN, but includes positional information, which will help with phrase search.